# How to get the current dataflow job's details using the Java SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to get the current dataflow job's details such as id, name, type, start time, end time etc., once the job is complete on the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner. Similar to the details we see in the dataflow dashboard,

[image]

I have used the below code to get the status,

```
    Pipeline p;
    ...
    ...
    PipelineResult result = p.run();

    switch (result.getState()) {
        case CANCELLED:
            break;
        case DONE:
            //MetadataTracker.insert(jobId, jobName, "Success", startTime, endTime);
        case FAILED:
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            break;
        case STOPPED:
            break;
        case UNKNOWN:
            break;
        case UPDATED:
            break;
        default:
            break;          
    }
```

However, the PipelineResult class doesn't have any methods to get the above mentioned details. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is the solution you used to getting the starttime and endtime? The below solution doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PipelineResult` contains information about an Apache Beam pipeline that is common to all runners. To get Dataflow-specific information from the Dataflow service, you can use the low-level [DataflowClient](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowClient.java). You'll also need the `jobId` which is available from `DataflowPipelineJob` (Dataflow's implementation of `PipelineResult`):

```
PipelineResult res = pipeline.run();
String jobId = ((DataflowPipelineJob) res).getJobId();
DataflowClient client = DataflowClient.create(options);
Job job = client.getJob(jobId);
```

`Job` contains all of the fields of interest. See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't work when the pipeline is started from a template.

Comment: @jkff This doesn't work for me. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been involved with Dataflow in a few years. You might want to ask on the Apache Beam user@ mailing list instead.